# How to call function at 8:30am every day

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to make a quiz app and I want it to show a new question every day at 8:30am and disappear at 6pm. I have seen online that the main way is to use timer but my question is if the person changes time zones, won't the timer be out of sync? Or does it restart every day? here is my code: (please note I am a beginner)

Also, whenever I load my app, the question appears for a second and then disappears and then appears again after the timer is up.

```
@objc func loadQuestion() {
    questionView.alpha = 0
    self.view.addSubview(questionView)
    questionView.center = self.view.center

    questionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.visualEffectView.effect = self.effect
        self.questionView.alpha = 1
        self.questionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(30600)
        let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loadQuestion), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
        }
    }

@objc func loadOutQuestion() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.questionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.questionView.alpha = 0

        self.visualEffectView.effect = nil

        let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(64800)
        let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loadOutQuestion), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)

    }) { (succcess:Bool) in
        self.questionView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about this... will your app always be on at 8:30 every day? Maybe say "if it is between 08:30 and 18:30 then ... "  Just check local time to your specified time range.

Answer (score 0):

This will get 8:30am and 6:00pm from user's local time.

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
let EightAM = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: startDate)!
let EightThirtyAM = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 30, to: EightAM)!
let SixPM = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 18, to: startDate)!
```

If the App isn't open at these times, nothing will fire.

What you could do in this case is in ViewDidLoad, check

```
if Date() > EightThirtyAM && Date() < SixPM {
     showQuiz()
} else {
     hideQuiz()
}
```

If you want it to disappear at 6:00pm on the dot add

```
let timer = Timer(fireAt: SixPM, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(hideQuiz), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

---

If you prefer a `component` solution try.

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: Date())
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: Date())
let timeFloat:Float = Float(hours) + Float(minutes)/60
if timeFloat > 8.5 && timeFloat < 18 {
    showQuiz
} else {
    hideQuiz
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It doesn't seem to be working for me. I think it has something to do with the animation I have.

Comment: I was able to make it work for the notifications using DateComponents. But I just can't figure it out with a normal function

Comment: What about an if-function? func > if > else

Comment: It doesn't let me apply > to two of type 'int?'

Comment: @Mateo sorry you have to unwrap the dates. Check edited code for the `!`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**Local Notification** I put apple sample code please check it and you can modify sample code as per your requirement.

The steps for configuring a local notification are as follows:

1. Create and configure a `UNMutableNotificationContent` object with the notification details.
2. Create a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`, `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`, or `UNLocationNotificationTrigger` object to describe the conditions under which the notification is delivered.
3. Create a `UNNotificationRequest` object with the content and trigger information.
4. Call the `addNotificationRequest:withCompletionHandler:` method to schedule the notification; see Scheduling Local Notifications for Delivery

[Official Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)

**Sample code**

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
// Replace "Wake up!" with your "question title"
content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Wake up!", arguments: nil)
// Replace "Rise and shine! It's morning time!" with your "question description"
content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Rise and shine! It's morning time!",
                                                        arguments: nil)

// Configure the trigger for a 7am wakeup.
var dateInfo = DateComponents()
dateInfo.hour = 7
dateInfo.minute = 0
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: false)

// Create the request object.
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MorningAlarm", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Comment: The "Local Notification" will work on functions that are not notifications? I already set up the notifications to go off at 8:30am. Can I link them?

Comment: Did you set up 'Remote Notification' for get off at 8:30 am ?

Comment: I think you need to set 'Local Notification' then after check your app launching with 'Local Notification' in this method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, If app launching with 'Local Notification' then you need to call your api for getting question for user, Or you can change your app flow as per your requirements.

Comment: I used UNCalendarNotificationTrigger and UNNotificationRequest, I'll try with that method and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far. I don't know if Im getting closer or farther from resolving this issue

```
@objc func loadQuestion() {
    self.view.addSubview(questionView)
    questionView.center = self.view.center

    questionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    questionView.alpha = 0

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 08
    dateComponents.minute = 30

    let currentTime = DateComponents()
    let hour = currentTime.hour
    let minute = currentTime.minute


    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

    if hour >= dateComponents {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.visualEffectView.effect = self.effect
            self.questionView.alpha = 1
            self.questionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
}
```